# Is there a way to use the searchFiles() method on an array of files rather than having to search through a folder by id (In Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I have a list of files in google drive that I want to search through to see if it contains a specific string.  I've found that using [searchfiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams) works perfectly to my need for identifying files with that string.

```
DriveApp.getFolderById('ID HERE').searchFiles('fullText contains "STRING"');
```

However, It's bound to having a folder to search through.

Is there another way that would mimic the ["fullText"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms#:%7E:text=s%20Day%27.-,fullText,-contains) search (i.e. one that would include the "name, description, indexableText properties or text in the file's content") but could do it through a list of file id's rather than being bound to a specific folder?

It seems pretty exhaustive to have to iterate through every folder in the Drive to do this when I already have a subset I want to crawl through.

(Frame of reference.  I have a list of files that already have a badged label from my central IT, and I want to use that list of files to search to assign a standard label.  I have all the other pieces figured out, but am stuck on this fact that searchFiles() only works on folders rather than an array or list of files.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams

Comment: I think that's the same link in my post?  If you're suggesting just using DriveApp.searchfiles() rather than going to the folder level, then I think that will only work  for the drive you are the owner of (would not include shared drives, sorry I failed to mention that)...but either way it doesn't address my question of because I have a list of file ID's that I want to search through.

Comment: Then try using Google Drive API

Comment: Drive.Files.list();

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of `I have a list of files in google drive`? What is `a list of files in google drive`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Cooper  I think I can modify my approach to my problem and use list() to accomplish my current immediate need...  However, don't see how list() can accomplish what I asked regarding doing a 'fullText contains' type search on a specific file.  If I'm missing something please provide an example of searching for a string within a specific file in Drive by File ID.  (e.g. q: 'fullText contains "string"')

Comment: @Tanaike what I mean to say is that I have an array of file Id's.  I want to search through those files in that array to see if the file's contain a string.  Similar to using the q: 'fullText contains "string".  Or even simpler, I want to look at a specific file by id and determine if that file contains "string".  The fullText concept is powerful for my need because it includes "name, description, indexableText properties or text in the file's content"

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `what I mean to say is that I have an array of file Id's. I want to search through those files in that array to see if the file's contain a string.`, in this case, if all files of file IDs are included in a specific folder, I think that `searchFiles` can be used. But, if those files are put into various folders and each folder has the files except for the files you want to search, `searchFiles` cannot be directly used.

Comment: By the way, I cannot know your actual situation. Can I ask you about the mimeTypes of the files you want to search? Because I think that the approach depends on the mimeType of the files. First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike they are not all in the same folder.  This is why I am asking the question.  mimeTypes are irrelevant I require it to search / query through all types of files.  This is why I compare it to the searchFiles() or the query parameter in list() because this searches the files completely (i.e. "name, description, indexableText properties or text in the file's content" per the documentation)

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `they are not all in the same folder.`, I understood it. About `mimeTypes are irrelevant`, in your situation, when the file is an image, what do you want to do?